# Creating new php page from admin panel

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make a blog page using php. What I'm stuck with is how to create this page when I want to create a new post from the admin panel?

Comment: Where is the code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Blog platforms don't generally create actual files for each post. They build them on the fly with data from a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a table of blog posts, and each record will be a stand-alone blog post that you display as a standalone page.

You then have a page, e.g. blog.php, which takes an id (or some form of reference to the blogpost you want to display), query the database for the given blog post and render the page.

I assume you have not posted any code / what you have tried because you have no idea how to get started, so I will also not give you any code, the description above should be enough for you to get started.

I see that you are a new user, so please in the future refrain from asking vague questions, without specific information as it is not allowed.